# How to index a table for a query with "order by if"?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

Is it possible to create an index to facilitate the ORDER BY in the following query where there is an IF condition, as follows?:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY IF(published, 0, 1), rank, title
```

I've tried creating an index on myTable(published, rank, title) and also an index on myTable(rank, title), but testing the query with EXPLAIN shows no index is employed.

"published" is a tinyint and is either 0 or 1; "rank" is also a tinyint, but could be any of the values in that range; "title" is varchar(255).

Many thanks (I'm working with code I've inherited from another developer...)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, it looks like the query could just be re-written as:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY published DESC, rank, title
```

In particular, this wouldn't work with arbitrary transformation functions, but would work in this example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no index that can help this query in MySQL.

The one thing you can do is to add a `PublishedFlag` to the table.  However, this requires a trigger for `update` and `inset`.  But, then this query:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY PublsihedFlag, rank, title
```

Can take advantage of an index on `mytable(PublsihedFlag, rank, title)`.

Comment: That works only if the _smaller_ value of PublsihedFlag is what you want _first_.

Comment: @RickJames . . . You can add `desc` if you want it in the opposite order.

Comment: True. But it won't be able to use the index.  All columns in the `ORDER BY` need to be the same direction for the index on those columns to be useful.

Comment: @RickJames . . . The `desc` can also be added to the index.

Comment: True.  But MySQL ignores it.